# Upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 using the instructions from the Dell website. It says that I need to download all the Updates and then Microsoft Store will popp up and I can upgrade from store.

Microsoft states that no upgrade through store is possible (from June 2019) and only upgrade through ISO file is possible.

Now I don’t know if I can trust my Windows 8.1 installation or I should reinstall Windows 8 and do the upgrade as Microsoft advises.

Comment: Since Windows 8/8.1 reached the end of Mainstream Support on January 9, 2018, why not move to a supported OS, e.g. Linux or Windows 10? No need to be *conflicted* about moving on... You'll treasure the change.

Comment: I have extensively documented the process of how to install Windows 8.1 Update 1 installation with a Windows 8 product key, what part of that process are you stuck on?  The process to upgrade to Windows 8.1 Update from an ISO is nearly identical to that process.

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-the-windows-8-1-update-kb-2919355-b189a9bd-0b33-f4a4-2092-4a5be0ebcb61  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/windows-81-microsoft-store-app-package-updates